Is there a word for thinking something is important when it actually isn't?
I feel like there's an adjective on the tip of my tongue, something along the lines of describing something that is 'believed to be stronger than it actually is' or 'believed to be more important than it actually is'.

Welcome to ELU. When requesting a single-word, please provide a sample sentence or two with an underscore ( ________ ) where the word is to go.


Its importance is exaggerated / overrated.
Its strength is exaggered / overrated.

exaggerated (adj.)

Excessively or inappropriately heightened, inflated, or overstated
exaggerated fears
a wildly exaggerated story
M-W

overrated (adj.)

Rated or valued too highly
an overrated book/movie/restaurant
M-W

The word you are looking for may be among the synonyms for the more common adjectives provided by an online dictionary. For example, M-W lists 25 for exaggerated.
